# Stop Spotlight from indexing Time Machine volume

Tags: backup, time-machine, spotlight, indexing

The following processes are running more or less constantly and are starting again after each Time Machine backup:

```
mds
mds_stores  
mdworker_shared
```

Terminal command `mdutil -s -v /Volumes/Backup` returns:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Backup:
    Indexing enabled. 
    Scan base time: 1970-01-01 00:00:01 +0000 (1644396457 seconds ago), reasoning: '(null)'
```

I tried to disable indexing for the backup volume with `sudo mdutil -i off /Volumes/Backup`, but it doesn't change anything and returns:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Backup:
2022-02-09 09:44:32.181 mdutil[36858:796873] mdutil disabling Spotlight: /System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Backup -> kMDConfigSearchLevelFSSearchOnly
    Indexing enabled.
```

Indexing the backup volume doesn't make any sense at all, does it?
Is there any way to stop it?

Dragging the volume icon into System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy returns `“Backup” is a Time Machine backup folder. You cannot add it to the privacy list.` and doesn't work either.

MacOS 12.2, MacBook Pro 14" 2021.

Comment: I think that if you could disable Spotlight for Time Machine volumes then Time Machine will not work.

Comment: @mmmmmm this seems to be true, but indexing takes a lot of time and starts after each hourly backup, which leads to the indexing processes running almost constantly.  
This seems odd and I didn't notice this behaviour before.

Comment: After an OS upgrade it does seem to take a few days to settle down

Comment: In `12.6.2` having the same problem. AFAI can tell, this is just another shitty design by Mac team. they assume they know better than you do how your computer should be used. I have TimeMachine effectively disabled, with no disks selected for use with backups, I have touched the volume containing timemachine data with `.netadata_never_index` etc, I have tried unsuccessfully to add the volume to be unsearchable in Spotlight/privacy tab, no avail. Only disabling sysprot and then spotlight might work.